# Setting up a passthrough rule in bison

Tags: c++, c, bison, flex-lexer

I have a parser generated using Flex/Bison - it parses each line of a file and returns some output for that line. My input data is a little corrupt, and what I'd like to do is add a special character (like a #) to the beginning of lines that I'd like bison to ignore, and merely echo the line to the output.

So if my input looked like

```
apples 3 ate
oranges 4 consumed
# rhino ten
```

my output after parsing the lines might be

```
I ate three apples
I consumed four oranges
# rhino ten
```

Is there some easy way to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this lexically in the flex scanner.

Something like:

```
^#.*\n   { fputs(yytext, stdout); /* increment line number */ }
```

Or in the parser:

```
^#.*\n   { yystype.lexeme = strdup(yytext);
           return HASH_ECHO; /* token type defined in parser */ }
```

In the parser just generate from your top level grammar a production for this:

```
/* in top section */
%union {
   /* ... */
   char *lexeme;
   /* ... */
}

%token<lexeme> HASH_ECHO
/*...*/

/* make sure this rule is hooked into your grammar, of course */
hash_echo : HASH_ECHO { fputs($1, stdout); free($1); }
          ;
```

Not sure about including that newline; I have no idea how you're handling those. So it may not be appropriate.

Comment: That correctly removes the entry from being parsed, but doesn't print it.

Comment: Maybe you were looking at an older edit. The fputs calls should print the lexeme. I used fputs, by the way, instead of puts because puts adds a newline, and we already have one.

Comment: Also, of course, when you see a # at the beginning of a line, your action can itself consume input characters until the end of line and print them as it goes. You don't have to make the lexer scan this as a lexeme.

Comment: @Kaz I would usually try not to output something in the scanner and the parser as this might fail if the parser needs to look ahead a token and the output is then unsynchronized.

Comment: Maybe you mean, don't output something in the lexer if the parser also produces output, because the lexer will race ahead and produce the output before the parser has decided what to do with the token, and so the lexer's output will be premature. That's why I included the second answer, which up the lexeme into a token and lets the parser print it in a rule action.